# Why can't I retrieve the master appointment of a series via `AppointmentCalendar.FindAppointmentsAsync`?

Tags: calendar, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm retrieving multiple appointments via `AppointmentCalendar.FindAppointmentsAsync`. I'm evaluating the `Recurrence.RecurrenceType` and noticed an unexpected value of `1` for master appointments of a series. I expect the `Recurrence.RecurrenceType` to be `0` (Master) but instead it is 1 (Instance).

(Note: I added `AppointmentProperties.Recurrence` to `FindAppointmentsOptions.FetchProperties` that is passed to `GetAppointmentsAsync`, so the `Recurrence` data should be fetched propertly.)

To double check I retrieved the respective master appointment via `GetAppointmentAsync` (instead of `FindAppointmentsAsync`) using its `LocalId` - and here the `RecurrenceType` is correctly set to `0`.

Here is demo output for a test appointment series:

Data gotten by `FindAppointmentsAsync` (Instance??):

```
"Recurrence": { 
    "Unit": 0, 
    "Occurrences": 16, 
    "Month": 1, 
    "Interval": 1, 
    "DaysOfWeek": 0, 
    "Day": 1, 
    "WeekOfMonth": 0, 
    "Until": "2016-09-29T02:00:00+02:00", 
    "TimeZone": "Europe/Budapest", 
    "RecurrenceType": 1, 
    "CalendarIdentifier": "GregorianCalendar" 
}, 
"StartTime": "2016-09-14T19:00:00+02:00", 
"OriginalStartTime": "2016-09-14T19:00:00+02:00",
```

Data gotten by `GetAppointmentAsync` for the same appointment (Master):

```
"Recurrence": { 
    "Unit": 0, 
    "Occurrences": 16, 
    "Month": 1, 
    "Interval": 1, 
    "DaysOfWeek": 0, 
    "Day": 1, 
    "WeekOfMonth": 0, 
    "Until": "2016-09-29T02:00:00+02:00", 
    "TimeZone": "Europe/Budapest", 
    "RecurrenceType": 0, 
    "CalendarIdentifier": "GregorianCalendar" 
    }, 
"StartTime": "2016-09-14T19:00:00+02:00", 
"OriginalStartTime": null,
```

Notice the difference in `RecurrenceType`. Also note that `OriginalStartTime` is set to `null` for the master gotten by `GetAppointmentAsync` but has a value for the appointment gotten by `FindAppointmentsAsync`.

You can also see that the `StartTime` for the master appointment is the start time set for the alleged Instance (which in reality is the master).

Shouldn't `FindAppointmentsAsync` return a *master* as the first element of a series, instead of an *instance*?

(SDK: 10.0.14393.0, Anniversary)

---

Code to explicitly find such a master/instance situation for a given calendar:

```
var appointmentsCurrent = await calendar.FindAppointmentsAsync(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(365), findAppointmentOptions); 
foreach(var a in appointmentsCurrent) 
{ 
    var a2 = await calendar.GetAppointmentAsync(a.LocalId);
    if (a2.Recurrence?.RecurrenceType == RecurrenceType.Master && 
    a2.StartTime == a.StartTime && 
    a.Recurrence?.RecurrenceType == RecurrenceType.Instance && 
    a.OriginalStartTime == a2.StartTime) 
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine("Gotcha!"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested above code on my side. If you get the count of the appointments which are got from `FindAppontmentsAsync` by the following code:`var count=appointmentsCurrent.Count`;, you will find it does return the count of the appointment instances, not the count of master appointments. So the [FindAppontmentsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn633795.aspx) method got all instances of the appointments not master appointments. This is the reason why the RecurrenceType is instance.

It seems like we can get one master appointment by method `GetAppointmentAsync` as you mentioned above, so I suppose this may not block you.

If you think this is not a good design for this API or you require a API for finding all the master appointments in one calendar, you can submit your ideas to the windows 10 feedback tool or the [user voice site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).